# Random characters being output when changing an integer from one base to another

Tags: c++

I'm working on an assignment where I'm supposed to convert an integer from one base to another. The program asks for the current base, the number in that current base, and the new base to be converted to.

I will input these values, for example:

```
Please enter the number's base:10
Please enter the number:4136490862
Please enter the new base: 10
```

And the output will be:

```
4136490862 base 10 is -2-1-4-7-4-8-3-6-4-8 base 10
```

The correct output is:

```
4136490862 base 10 is 4136490862 base 10
```

There are other test cases, this is just one of them that isn't working.

I've been stuck on this for days. Does anyone know where I am going wrong?

Here is the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <istream>
#include <cmath>
 
int main(void){
 
    std::string num;
    int currentBase;
    int newBase;
    int lastDigit;
    int i = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int remainder;
    std::string new_number = "";
 
 
    //Get the current base from the user
    std::cout <<"Please enter the number's base: ";
    std::cin >> currentBase;
 
    //enter the number of that base
    std::cout <<"Please enter the number: ";
    std::cin >> num;
 
    //enter the new base you want to convert it to
    std::cout <<"Please enter the new base: ";
    std::cin >> newBase;
 
    //just a check to see if the base is valid cuz valid bases are only from 2-36
    if ((currentBase < 2) || (currentBase > 36) || (newBase < 2) || (newBase > 36)){
        std::cout << "One or more of the bases that you entered are not valid!" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
 
    //Convert the input string to base 10
    //iterate through the number from least significant to most significant digit
    for(int j = num.size() - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        char c = num[j];
        if (isdigit(c)) {
            lastDigit = c - '0';
        } else if (isupper(c)) {
            lastDigit = c - 'A' + 10;
        } else if (islower(c)) {
            lastDigit = c - 'a' + 10;
        }
        sum += lastDigit * pow(currentBase, i);
        i++;
    }
 
    //Convert the base 10 number to the desired base
    while (sum != 0) {
        remainder = sum % newBase;
        if (remainder < 10) {
            new_number = std::to_string(remainder) + new_number;
        } else {
            new_number = char(remainder - 10 + 'A') + new_number;
        }
        sum /= newBase;
    }
 
    //print everything out
    std::cout << num << " base " << currentBase << " is " << new_number << " base " << newBase << std::endl;
 
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: `sum` is an `int`. What is the largest value it can hold?

Comment: Please note that `pow(currentBase, i)` might not be a good idea due to the potentially imprecise floating point calculation and subsequent truncation to an integer value. Also, adding a char at a time *in front* of a string is a relative expansive solution compared to adding the chars to the *back* and then reversing (in place) the string.

Comment: This won’t fix the problem, but to accumulate the initial value, use `sum = sum * currentBase + lastDigit`.

Answer (score 3):

`4136490862` cannot be stored in an `int`. I assume the intent is that you should use `unsigned int` instead, but the easier and safer solution is to use `long long`.

Comment: The highest number that a signed `int` can hold in most compilers is `2147483647`, see [`std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max)

Comment: 4136490862 is actually stored as a string not an int. Would that still be an issue?

Comment: @ryan You are storing the user's input into a `string`, but then you are converting its digits into `int`, performing `int` math on them, and summing them onto a final `int`, which eventually overflows. You are then storing the digits of the overflowed value to another `string`. So yes, this is still an issue.